# Use Google AppEngine SDK to run my application on a private server

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk

If I for some reason wanted to use my own private server to run my GAE app instead of deploying it to Google servers, could I simply use AppEngine SDK to do that? Are there any technical or legal limitations or problems that I should know about? I know that the SDK isn't designed to run heavy pages but for small websites it should work right?

Comment: By SDK, do you mean using dev_appserver?

Comment: I would highly recommend not using it for anyone buy yourself on your local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could try. I'm not aware of any legal issues (with the caveat that I Am Not A Lawyer, and can't offer to interpret the license agreement for you), but I doubt you'd be happy with performance.

For one, the dev_appserver Datastore emulation (in both the Python and Java SDKs) doesn't scale all that well once you're past small amounts of data. It's not designed for performance; it's designed to accurately mimic the semantics of the real Datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't plan to do it, I was just wondering if it was theoretically possible.

Answer (score 9):

The dev_appserver is not built to serve public-facing traffic. It's single-threaded, not built for performance, the backends are likewise limited, and it exposes administrative endpoints (such as /_ah/admin/) which users should not be able to access.

Alternatives exist for hosting your app yourself, such as [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) and [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).